# The image of non-reflexive Banach space in its bidual is at large distance from some unit vector in the bidual

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am having some difficulties with part of a problem, I am working on.

> Let $X$ be a non-reflexive Banach space and let $i: X \to X^{**}$ be the canonical embedding.
>   Show that for given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $x^{**} \in X^{**}$, such that $\|x^{**}\|=1$ and $$\inf_{x \in X} \|x^{**} - i(x)\|_{X^{**}} > 1- \epsilon.$$

I have no idea how to show more than the existence of some $x^{**} \in X^{**}$, such that $\|x^{**}\|=1$ and $$\inf_{x \in X} \|x^{**} - i(x)\|_{X^{**}} > 0,$$ which is by definition of reflexivity and closeness of $i(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [Riesz lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma) as $i(X)$ is norm-closed in $X^{**}$.